# select * from [Table] where Column not in (Null)

Tags: sql

I was executing this query

```
select CardId, CardHeader from [Card] 
where CardId not in (select CardId from RoleMap where RoleId = 2)
```

the output of `(select CardId from RoleMap where RoleId = 2)` is `null`

and the output is 0 rows affected

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: `not in (null)` returns no rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using left join

```
select CardId, CardHeader from [Card] a left join RoleMap b on a.CardId =b.CardId 
and RoleId = 2
where b.cardid is not null
```

Comment: I think this is not what I am trying to do. My query is supposed to return rows from Card table which has CardId that does not exist in the RoleMap table.

Comment: Have you tried this query @MohanKurali - it will give you those records which are not present in RoleMap table

Comment: I executed your query. It is not returning all the expected rows. I think join condition should be <>.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CardId, CardHeader 
FROM   [Card] 
WHERE  CardId NOT IN (SELECT ISNULL(CardId, 0) from RoleMap WHERE RoleId = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select t.* from [Card] t
where  not exists (select 1 from RoleMap t1 where RoleId = 2
                                     and t1.CardId=t.CardId)
```